# python : numpy: just like list can i change the type of value for an item

Tags: python, numpy

Generally in python I can do the

```
a = [0.0]
a[0] = (1,2)
print(a)
```

output:

```
[(1, 2)]
```

Where as with numpy i tried

```
a = np.zeros((1,))
# it produces array([0.])
a[0] = (1,2)
print(a)
```

I get:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'
```

How can i manage to get similar behaviour with numpy like python list.

I need flexibility to change the value in the list as i want.

Comment: Two things: Recommend renaming the `tuple` variable as you’re currently overwriting the built in. And per [the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) the `append` function must be assigned, as the action *does not* occur in-place.

Comment: Additionally, `np.array((0,))` is not an empty array, it will contain a zero.  Recommend changing to `np.array(())`.

Comment: Regarding the actual error, I cannot replicate.  Please provide the full traceback.

Comment: Can you check now. I simplified the question

Comment: The `a` array contains 1 float element (shape (1,)).  You can't change that element to a tuple.  That's a basic `numpy` property.  DON'T skip the `numpy 101` reading!  There are things you can do with lists that you can't with arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try  `a = np.zeros(1, dtype=tuple)`

Comment: using this i can change to anything, even a list or object eg: `a[0]=[datetime.datetime.now(),10,100]` or `a[0]={"test": datetime.datetime.now()}` and tuple or interger anything. thanks

how is this possible with tuple type i can modify the type to anything

Comment: my self I am very bad at explaining but this page might help i am so sorry https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html or this https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Comment: even `dtype=object` also work

Comment: Any `dtype` that isn't the defined numeric or string ones (`float32` etc), is actually rendered as `object`.  When you use this, the array stores references to Python objects, nearly the same as a list does.  About the only thing it adds, compared to a list, is reshaping and fancier indexing.